# Box2d DebugDraw in Cocos2djs

Tags: box2d, game-physics, cocos2d-js, box2dweb

I am trying to get box2d debugdaw working in cocos2djs. The following code for me just runs the game normally without any errors or debug shapes. Where am I going wrong?

```
var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2
    , b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World
    , b2BodyDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2BodyDef
    , b2Body = Box2D.Dynamics.b2Body
    , b2FixtureDef = Box2D.Dynamics.b2FixtureDef
    , b2PolygonShape = Box2D.Collision.Shapes.b2PolygonShape
    , b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw;

// Construct a world object, which will hold and simulate the rigid bodies.
this.world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, -10), true);
this.world.SetContinuousPhysics(true);

var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
debugDraw.SetSprite(cc.renderContext);
debugDraw.SetDrawScale(PTM_RATIO);
debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.8);
debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit);
this.world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
```

Then I add the world borders and physics bodies.

Thanks in advance.
Zain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the following instead of using debugDraw?

`var debugNode = new cc.PhysicsDebugNode(space);
debugNode.visible = true;
this.addChild(debugNode);`

I know this works for Chipmunk integration, I'm not sure for box2d, but it should work.

Comment: ya i tried it, doesn't seem to work for box2d. I ended up moving to chipmunk, it seems easier for js.